# Eclipse LUNA:Not able to get pmd in preferences

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am able to install the eclipse pmd 1.5 plugin for eclipse luna successfully.But after restarting eclipse I ma not able to find PMD under preferences section and hence I am unable to use PMD with eclipse.

If I am referring to wrong plugin .Please help me out with getting pmd in preferences.